# Metropolitan Statistical Area map

Tags: dictionary, d3.js

Is there a d3 map that plots MSA codes in the U.S.?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Metropolitan_and_Micropolitan_Statistical_Areas_of_the_United_States_and_Puerto_Rico.gif

Answer (score 2):

I was on the hunt for a similar MSA-level resource and discovered this map at the CartoDB website: https://common-data.cartodb.com/tables/cb_2013_us_cbsa_5m/public/map

[image]

You can download several different formats, including GeoJSON.

I hope this is helpful to others who come across this post!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DMA version: http://bl.ocks.org/simzou/6459889

I'm not familiar with other MSA maps available.

Comment: thanks for the link out to DMAs. But how are DMA's related to MSA's?

Answer (score -1):

You will find your geojson files here: http://brenocon.com/geocode/